# Lazy loading and the use of Thread.MemoryBarrier

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, lazy-loading, memory-barriers

When designing a class that has a reference to another object it might be beneficial to only create the referenced object the first time it is used, e.g. use lazy loading.

I often use this pattern to create a lazy loaded property:

```
Encoding utf8NoBomEncoding;

Encoding Utf8NoBomEncoding {
  get {
    return this.utf8NoBomEncoding ?? 
      (this.utf8NoBomEncoding = new UTF8Encoding(false));
  }
}
```

Then I came across this code when browsing the source code for the BCL:

```
Encoding Utf8NoBomEncoding {
  get {
    if (this.utf8NoBomEncoding == null) {
      var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
      Thread.MemoryBarrier();
      this.utf8NoBomEncoding = encoding;
    }
    return this.utf8NoBomEncoding;
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell none of these are thread safe. E.g. multiple `Encoding` objects may be created. I completely get that and know that it isn't a problem if an extra `Encoding` object is created. It is immutable and will soon be garbage collection.

**However, I'm really curious to understand why `Thread.MemoryBarrier` is necessary and how the second implementation is different from the first in multi-threading scenarios.**

Obviously, if thread safety is a concern the best implementation is probably to use `Lazy<T>`:

```
Lazy<Encoding> lazyUtf8NoBomEncoding = 
  new Lazy<Encoding>(() => new UTF8Encoding(false));

Encoding Utf8NoBomEncoding {
  get {
    return this.lazyUtf8NoBomEncoding.Value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating multiple `Encoding` objects is not a problem, since all the copies behave identically. (Note also that `Lazy<T>` was not available at the time the code was written.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code would be a disaster without the memory barrier. Look closely at these lines of code.

```
  var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
  Thread.MemoryBarrier();
  this.utf8NoBomEncoding = encoding;
```

Now, imagine some other thread sees the effects of the last line but doesn't see the effects of the first line. That would be a complete disaster.

The memory barrier ensures that any thread that sees `encoding` at all also sees all the effects of its constructor.

For example, without the memory barrier, the first and last lines could be internally optimized (roughly) as follows:
1) Allocate some memory, store a pointer to it in this.utf8NoBomEncoding
2) Call the UTF8Encoding constructor to fill in that memory with valid values.

Imagine if between steps 1 and 2 another thread runs and passes through this code. It will use an object that has not been constructed yet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Does that mean that the first code sample in my question can be optimized into something that might fail like you describe it?

Comment: Yes. Nothing ensures the object is valid before it's made available to other threads.

Comment: Correct, the JIT is free to reorder instructions as long as they appear to be in the same order when viewed from the standpoint _of a single thread_. This is why the double-checked locking idiom is broken without the use of memory barriers (or volatile), for this same reason.

Answer (score 2):

This pattern is fairly common in .NET.  It is possible because UTF8Encoding is an immutable class.  Yes, more than one instance of the class can be created but that does not matter since all instances are the same.  Enforced with an Equals() override.  The extra copies will be quickly garbage collected.  The memory barrier just ensures that the object state is fully visible.

Comment: It can be very misleading when you look at code from a reputable source that does something, you think you're doing the same thing, but the other code actually only works because of some absurdly subtle detail that's not mentioned in comments or anything. That's just mean.

Comment: Feh, Reflector is not a reputable source :)